# Rounded inside corner at the intersection of two planes

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, topology, bevel

I'm trying unsuccesfully to reproduce a detail at the inside corner of two planes that meet are perpedicular with one having a bevel. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Example of inside rounded corner:

[image: Example of inside rounded corner]

Here is the current state of my model:

[image: Current state of model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

Create this shape:

[image]

Bevel the edge:

[image]

Cut a circle shape with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Cut this edge with the knife:

[image]

Cut off the faces, remove the overlapping or useless vertices, give it a *Solidify* modifier, a *Bevel* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do some complex modeling although it is good to learn how to do thinks in the previous answer.

***Your approach is in the right direction you just use too many polygons from the beginning.***

If no specific angles and measurements are required you can utilize the magic of subdivision surfaces.

[image]

1. Start with evenly spaced squares (**Array modifier** is a good approach, then **apply the modifier**)
2. Connect the gaps between the squares with faces.
3. Extrude edges as shown on the third step at distance approximately the distance of the "gaps".
4. Extrude the edges down twice as shown on the 4th step.
5. Add **Subdivision Surface modifier** with level 2 or bigger. Play with the edges locations until satisfied.
6. Add **Solidify modifier** for thickness.

Comment: I am indeed doing this as an exercise in modeling, not necessarily for the end product itself. I will try you method as well.